# How to “Add guest” to event via google calendar API in IOS

Tags: ios, google-api, google-calendar-api

could you please give me a hint on how to share a single event via google calendar api with add guest?

That is I'd like to invite other users to see the event programmatically without sharing the whole calendar. To mimic the "Add guests" UI action

[image]

Comment: You can add the attendees to attendees[] using Calendar API, events.update. check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update

Comment: @SGC How to pass request body ?